# Large Text Files versus Small tex files

Tags: c#, winforms, io

This is just a general question? I have an application that uses the `File.ReadAllLines` and i was wondering, is it easier to load as one big file or multiple small files.

My current file is a Dictionary for my speech recognition. Currently it has about 40,000 lines in it. When i start the program it takes about 2 minutes for it to load the grammars.

When the file is less than 1,000 lines it processes and reads all line instantly. When added phases two implementing the Entire King James Bible. It slowed down tremendously.

So for better performance would be better to have multiple smaller files instead of one big file? I will be adding 16 more txt documents with each file roughly 2,000 to 3,000 lines in each txt document.

If its easier and faster to have several smaller then i wont bother adding them to one big file.

I am building a custom Speech Dictation engine, so it will consist of The KJV Bible, names, numbers and different NLP variations. Eventually i will be adding the Exhaustive Strong Concordance. So far the program works perfectly. I am just trying to get faster load times, on the initial start up.

Comment: You have heard of databases, right? Also, reading many smaller files is probably not faster, or even slower, than reading one big file. Reading many files has overhead for opening and closing the files. Also, one big file may be precached by the harddisk (driver) for faster access, while this can not be done if you read many files, as the disk/driver doesn't know what to read next.

Comment: yes but to be honest i have never used databases. It has always been easier for me to do it this way. Every time i tried using a database it never worked. I tried oracle and after fighting with it for a month i said screw it

Comment: Do you read the file each time you start the application? It would be better to read the file once at same it to a database, e.g. SQLite. Splitting the file into multiple small documents shouldn't shorten the loading time as you are still reading the same amount of data. Keep it as one file, but optimize your loading process and use a DB.

Comment: @campnerd You really should start using a database. The way you do it you have a *massive* memory overhead.

Comment: it`s really a good idea to use databases, if you expect to have extra high performance - might consider NO SQL as well.

Comment: https://github.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases or
http://simoncozens.github.io/open-source-bible-data/

Comment: all right i will look in to the db's and also are there any good ones as far as db's go? I have fought with Oracle before and that really turned me off on db's. Apache is not that good either.

Comment: @Greg i have already got the Bible in txt form.. However, if you know of a Strongs concordance txt file laying around that would help

Comment: @campnerd Apache is not a database. You could use Sql Server Express (very well integrated with Visual Studio and .NET) or MySQL. Both of these require you to install a database server. SQLite or Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition do not require a server to be installed. Other people have suggested no-sql databases. You could look at Mongo DB here.

Comment: now how will the app manifest go when i decided to release it and get in the big boy game with the Dragon Speech?